# Should a GWT RequestFactory Locator method expect a passed-in JPA entity to be attached or detached?

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

Right now I have to call JPA merge() at the end of my service method to persist changes. I'm doing this because our servlets do not start a transaction before the Locator.find() runs. They start them later in the service method.

I know that RequestFactory uses my Locator find() and updates the object based on what the client sent to the server, so I was just wondering if maybe that object should be an attached object and therefore allow JPA to handle the changes "naturally" rather than explicitly call merge().

Or perhaps this just depends on the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know JPA much, but I confirm that you **SHOULD** scope your transactions to your service methods: a `RequestContext` is a batch of requests that can each succeed or fail *independently*, putting them all in a single transactions would violates that principle. There are also cases where your `Localor#find` can be called, changes applied to the entity, but then the entity is never passed to any service method: you wouldn't want the changes to be persisted in this case.